# Group by, Order by not working correctly - SQL mode - ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, group-by, sql-order-by

Only_full_group_by mode is enabled.

My query is on table join of 2 tables -
If i just fetch the data using below query - it works correctly and shows me correct records:

```
select p.product_category, m.profit 
from market_fact m inner join
     prod_dimen p
     on m.prod_id = p.prod_id;`
```

but if I use group by order by Profit desc using below, it gives no. of records correct ans same - but does not give correct order and and even profit values are not same

```
select p.product_category, m.profit 
from market_fact m inner join
     prod_dimen p
     on m.prod_id = p.prod_id
order by m.Profit desc;
```

if I use group by product category and order by profit -

```
select p.product_category, m.profit 
from market_fact m inner join
     prod_dimen p
     on m.prod_id = p.prod_id
group by p.Product_Category
order by m.Profit desc;
```

then - it throws error:
Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'superstoresdb.m.Profit' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

How to approach this?

Comment: You need to provide sample data and results so we can see what the issues are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide an aggregration calculation (for example SUM, AVG, MAX, MIN) to m.profit otherwise SQL will think you want to GROUP BY it.

So if you want to see product categories by total profit try the code below:

```
select p.product_category, SUM(m.profit) as profit 
from market_fact m inner join
     prod_dimen p
     on m.prod_id = p.prod_id
group by p.product_Category
order by SUM(m.profit) desc;
```

If you don't want to do an aggregration calculation and just want to remove duplicates you are better off using a SELECT DISTINCT clause rather than GROUP BY:

```
select distinct p.product_category, m.profit
from market_fact m inner join
     prod_dimen p
     on m.prod_id = p.prod_id
order by m.profit desc;
```